# Image Compression using SVD

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, image-compression

I've been researching on image compression with SVD for school. However, I do not see how there will be a reduction in memory by using SVD and truncating the number of singular values used. The original image would be m x n in size, thereby using m x n x pixel-size bytes.
After SVD the resultant matrix is still m x n. Would it not then use the same amount of space?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the rank-`k` approximation of the image requires you to store (think about saving the image into a file) only the first `k` singular vectors and singular values, resulting in a `m x k` storage space instead of `m x n`. Then, when you want to render the image on screen you are obviously uncompressing it back to the `m x n` size (as you do with any other kind of compression), but that's not the true size of the image, is only rendering.